# Error: #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been given a database file to upload to my server but am getting the following error message when importing. I've searched for other similar problems but can't work out how to fix this.

SQL query:

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `wp_comments`
--   

INSERT INTO  `wp_comments` (  
     `comment_ID` ,  
     `comment_post_ID` ,
     `comment_author` ,
     `comment_author_email` ,
     `comment_author_url` ,
     `comment_author_IP` ,
     `comment_date` ,
     `comment_date_gmt` ,
     `comment_content` ,
     `comment_karma` ,
     `comment_approved` ,
     `comment_agent` ,
     `comment_type` ,
     `comment_parent` ,
     `user_id` 
    ) 
    VALUES 
    ( 
     1, 
     1,  
     'Mr WordPress',
     '', 
     'http://wordpress.org/',
     '', 
     '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
     '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
     'Hi, this is a comment.<br />To delete a comment, just log in and view the post&#039;s comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.',
     0,
     '1', 
     '', 
     '', 
     0,
     0 
    );
```

MySQL said:

> `#1062` - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Seems like you're trying to insert a value that already exists where only unique values are allowed. I assume it's "comment_ID".

Comment: please dump your wp_comments table CREATE statement

Comment: Please read and interpret the error message, it contains all the information you need to solve the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL weird issue while importing a large file: Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990908/mysql-weird-issue-while-importing-a-large-file-duplicate-entry-for-key-primary)

Comment: The error is very clear, I don't know how else we can tell.

Answer (score 1):

comment_ID column in your  wp_comments table is set as PRIMARY KEY, thus disallowing multiple records with same comment_ID value to be inserted into the table.

In your case, you already have a record with value "1" inserted, so you either have to remove that record (or empty the whole table) manually, or start inserting from a different comment_ID, or simply omit the comment_ID column and value, and it will most likely be automatically populated.

Reformat your query to look like this:

```
INSERT INTO wp_comments ( comment_ID, comment_post_ID , comment_author , comment_author_email , comment_author_url , comment_author_IP , comment_date , comment_date_gmt , comment_content , comment_karma , comment_approved , comment_agent , comment_type , comment_parent , user_id )
VALUES ( null, 1, 'Mr WordPress', '', 'http:////wordpress.org//', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', "Hi, this is a comment. To delete a comment, just log in and view the post's comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.", 0, '1', '', '', 0, 0 ) ;
```

Where the value for comment_ID is **null**, OR

```
INSERT INTO wp_comments ( comment_post_ID , comment_author , comment_author_email , comment_author_url , comment_author_IP , comment_date , comment_date_gmt , comment_content , comment_karma , comment_approved , comment_agent , comment_type , comment_parent , user_id )
VALUES (1, 'Mr WordPress', '', 'http:////wordpress.org//', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', "Hi, this is a comment. To delete a comment, just log in and view the post's comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.", 0, '1', '', '', 0, 0 ) ;
```

Where the comment_ID and it's value are omitted entirely.

In both cases, MySQL will assign the next auto-incremented value automatically.

Comment: Hi, I have tried reformatting both ways but still unsuccessful. Top reformat, get this message: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.', 0, '1', '',' at line 6

Comment: You have an apostrophe in your query. Either remove it or replace single quotes around the whole string with double quotes.

Comment: Sorry for sounding like a complete novice but whereabouts on here...

VALUES (null, 1, 'Mr WordPress', '', 'http://wordpress.org/', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'Hi, this is a comment. To delete a comment, just log in and view the post's comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.', 0, '1', '', '', 0, 0 ) ;

Comment: No problem, I have edited the corrected solution in the answer. Try it now.

Comment: SQL query:

--
-- Dumping data for table `wp_comments`
--
INSERT INTO wp_comments( comment_ID, comment_post_ID, comment_author, comment_author_email, comment_author_url, comment_author_IP, comment_date, comment_date_gmt, comment_content, comment_karma, comment_approved, comment_agent, comment_type, comment_parent, user_id ) 
VALUES (

NULL , 1,  'Mr WordPress',  '',  'wordpress.org/';

MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

Comment: I see. I have escaped your forward slashes, try again.

Comment: Could you correct this please...

VALUES (null, 1, 'Mr WordPress', '', 'http:////wordpress.org//';, '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'Hi, this is a comment. To delete a comment, just log in and view the post's comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.', 0, '1', '', '', 0, 0 ) ;

Comment: Try this: INSERT INTO wp_comments ( comment_post_ID , comment_author , comment_author_email , comment_author_url , comment_author_IP , comment_date , comment_date_gmt , comment_content , comment_karma , comment_approved , comment_agent , comment_type , comment_parent , user_id )
VALUES (1, "Mr WordPress", "", "http:////wordpress.org", "", "0000-00-00 00:00:00", "0000-00-00 00:00:00", "Hi, this is a comment. To delete a comment, just log in and view the post's comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.", 0, "1", "", "", 0, 0 ) ;

Comment: Back to the initial error :(

#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: INSERT INTO wp_comments (comment_author , comment_author_email , comment_author_url , comment_author_IP , comment_date , comment_date_gmt , comment_content , comment_karma , comment_approved , comment_agent , comment_type , comment_parent , user_id ) VALUES ("Mr WordPress", "", "http:////wordpress.org", "", "0000-00-00 00:00:00", "0000-00-00 00:00:00", "Hi, this is a comment. To delete a comment, just log in and view the post's comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.", 0, "1", "", "", 0, 0 ) ; However, I'm afraid this will lead to a new problem, which is out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Were you trying to migrate a WordPress site?

If so, if you did the following, the above mentioned error will occur.

1. You made a backup of your WordPress MySQL database
2. You setup a new WordPress site
3. You then tried to restore the backup in this newly
   setup WordPress site

After step 2 you should first delete all tables from the new WordPress database into which you will restore the backup in step 3.

The error messages appears becauase you've tried to import the MySQL dump (database file) into a non-empty WordPress database. When you setup a WordPress site it creates the needed tables, and inserts a few example records such as a comment. So, there's already a comment with id==1 in your database, and your backup tries to add another comment with id==1 (most likely the first real comment added on your website).

Answer (score -2):

You probably didnt AUTO_INCREMENT the Primary Key. An example can be found here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/example-auto-increment.html

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: its a wordpress table, and already have auto increments on primaries.

Comment: Oh wordpress ... okay, forget what i wrote.